# How do I override GetHashCode in a general BaseClass

Tags: c#

There's a lot of information on the internet about how to override GetHashCode() when Equals is overriden. But, all these examples are about classes that contain a few fields that can generate a hash.
What I'm trying to find is a good GetHashCode implementation for a base class I use for all my business logica layer objects. This class, called BusinessLogica, contains a ToString() implementation, some basic functionality for my framework and the following Equals override:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool retValue;

        if (obj is BusinessLogica && this.GetType() == obj.GetType())
        {
            retValue = this.ID == ((BusinessLogica)obj).ID;
        }
        else
        {
            retValue = false;
        }

        return retValue;
    }
```

Now, what I've done so far is when I need an object that extends this BusinessLogica and which I use as a key in a dictionary, I override GetHashCode in this particular class and return ID.
I could also use this implementation in the BusinessLogica baseclass. Is this 'safe'? I've also seen examples where ToString().GetHashCode() is returned.

What would be wise to use? Or is a GetHashCode on this level not usable and should I really override it in every of my BusinessLogica classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only use the `ID` property to test for equality then that's almost certainly what you should use to derive your hashcode too.

If `ID` is an `Int32` then returning `this.ID` from the `GetHashCode` method should be fine. If `ID` is some other type then you could return `this.ID.GetHashCode()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general idea is that - if you have redefined equals, then the following invariant must hold

**2 objects that are equal must have the same hashcode. (The other way around may not be true).**

Also see this question for an implementation - [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328). In your example, however I think you can just use the ID attribute for your hashcode generation.

*Assumption: it upholds the above invariant. Also it is immutable, once an object is created, the ID shouldn't change.*

Answer (score 0):

`Equals(...)` and `GetHashCode(...)` should always be implemented equivalently.

If you determine that your objects are equal by their `ID` (although that is debatable), then you should also return the HashCode of the `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ID to determine if objects are equal your `GetHashCode` implementation should be using ID too:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return this.ID.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to always remember when writing an `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method is that you should never have one without the other and that they agree with eachother. So in this case returning `ID` as the hash code (or the hash code of `ID` which is the same) is perfectly ok.